# How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#

I want to add my existing solution to Github and I've watched lots of youtube videos. But all of them only showed me about creating new projects. How can I add the existing project on Github? There is no File-> Add to source control option in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition!

Comment: Just read this https://github.com/blog/2285-github-extension-now-supports-visual-studio-2017-rc

Comment: Create a new repository from github first then push your code into it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can achieve it by following below steps :

```
1.Open the solution in Visual Studio 2017
2.Select File | Add to Source Control
3.Select the Microsoft Git Provider
```

That creates a local GIT repository

```
1.Browse to GitHub
2.Create a new repository DO NOT SELECT Initialize this repository with a README
```

That creates an empty repository with no Master branch

```
1.Once created open the repository and copy the URL (it's on the right of the screen in the current version)
2.Go back to Visual Studio
Make sure you have the Microsoft Git Provider selected under Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in Selection
3.Open Team Explorer
4.Select Home | Unsynced Commits
5.Enter the GitHub URL into the yellow box (use HTTPS URL, not the default shown SSH one)
6.Click Publish
7.Select Home | Changes
8.Add a Commit comment
9.Select Commit and Push from the drop down
```

I hope this helps , your solution is now in Github

Comment: Don't see "Home | Unsynced Commits" in step 4

Comment: I pressed "Sync" panel (with the up/down arrow icon) and then selected "Push to Remote Repository", added my GitHub URL and pressed "Publish". Worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

> 2.Select File | Add to Source Control

Doesn't exist in VS 2017 Community.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. It works fine in community edition. See my answer for steps.

Answer (score 3):

Here are step by step instructions:

https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/cloning-a-repository-to-visual-studio.md

this works in community edition.

Comment: Works like a charm, with, like 2 or 3 simple steps. Great, thanks.

Comment: This link discusses cloning an existing repository to GitHub.  How would I add a solution to GitHub from VS2019?

Comment: I have noticed that there is no "Add to Source Control" option in the File menu for Visual Studio 2019.  So far it looks like a completely manual solution is required to add an existing solution to GitHub.  I have gone into the Tools | Options and verified my settings.  There is no way that I can find to do this from the GitHub extension in VS 2019.