# Visual Studio 2017 & github error when creating repo

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I'm struggling trying to get my first project from Visual Studio 2017 up onto GitHub.

Where I'm stuck is trying to create a repo from Visual Studio.  I made one online called the same thing as my VS Project (SHLiC).  I then actually read the directions and realized it's easier to create the repo from VS itself.  So I deleted the repo, made sure it was gone by searching in GitHub for it, then tried to create the repo in VS.  That's where I'm stuck.  It appears that it's stuck on a naming collision "somewhere"...and I can't find any logs to find specific errors.

When I make the name something else, the error goes away.  Here's all I see on the screen:

[image: GitHub Error image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on?  Or even where the logs are to look?  I've tried `%LocalAppData%\GitHubVisualStudio\extension.log` and `%LocalAppData%\Temp\extension.log` with no help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this that may find this, I found [How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217847/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2017) was a big help.  The directions were a bit old and missing some bits, but I was able to make it work.

Short version is to create a repo on GitHub, get its URL, then have Visual Studio commit there.